# Count Distinct is less than Sum(Count Distinct)

Tags: sql, distinct

I have two queries:

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN EVENT_NAME = 'event' THEN UPPER(user END)) AS SIGNUP_COUNT,
from table
WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-09-01'
```

and

```
with EVENTS_FILTERED_with_count as (  
select *
, COUNT(DISTINCT (CASE WHEN EVENT_NAME = 'event' THEN UPPER(user END)) AS SIGNUP_COUNT
from table
group by 1)

SELECT sum(SIGNUP_COUNT) FROM EVENTS_FILTERED_with_count
WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-09-01'
```

The first query returns 2.5K rows as result, and the second one returns 3K rows.

Why would adding the group by make the result larger? I'm wondering if it has to do with NULL values.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Please show *valid* SQL, and also explain in what way the question title is related to the SQL shown, given that the SQL doesn't do any `Sum(Count Distinct)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the same `user` has multiple events, so the event is counted multiple times when counted at the user level.

It is hard to be more descriptive without sample data.

Comment: got it, that makes sense. So that means a user can have multiple instances of "event" by different columns in the group by rather than just the user by itself

Comment: @nak5120 . . . Multiple instances across whatever the `group by` key is.

Comment: exactly, yup this makes sense. Thank you!